# mbind: Operation not permitted when connecting with sequel pro

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm running MySQL 8.0 inside a docker container for local development. The web container can connect to mysql just fine. When trying to access my database from Sequel Pro, the container gives me an error,

`db_1   | mbind: Operation not permitted`

It should be noted that connecting with MySQL Workbench does not cause the container to throw that error, but it also doesn't full connect. It does display the database and tables, but fails to query the tables. I've included the error from Sequel Pro below.

```
NSInvalidArgumentException

-[_NSInlineData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000039740

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3cae52fb         __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff63452c76     objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3cb7dda4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3ca5b670 ___forwarding___ + 1456
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3ca5b038 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Sequel Pro                          0x000000010002fce3 -[SPDatabaseDocument setDatabases:] + 783
    6   Sequel Pro                          0x000000010002f2a9 -[SPDatabaseDocument setConnection:] + 610
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff3eb56985 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 334
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3ca7d821 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3cb374cc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 108
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3ca602c0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3ca5f73d __CFRunLoopRun + 1293
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3ca5efa3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
    13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3bd7e866 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3bd7e5d6 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
    15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3bd7e354 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff3a07ba23 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff3a810e6c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff3a070831 -[NSApplication run] + 764
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff3a03f9d2 NSApplicationMain + 804
    20  Sequel Pro                          0x0000000100002454 start + 52
```

)

Comment: What query are you trying to run in sqlpro?  Can you provide some info on the database architecture?

Comment: I get that error when I connect to the container. Not from any query I am running or from connecting to a specific database.

Comment: Could you @DylanButh Werlich please accept or vote for my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with SequelPro not supporting mysql8.

Comment: For anyone ending up here, https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2699#issuecomment-432431710
helped resolve the issue.

Comment: For anyone ending up here more recently, to save you getting to the end of the GitHub discussion, try the forked version of Sequel Pro: Sequel Ace: https://github.com/Sequel-Ace/Sequel-Ace Using that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

I get that error as well from the mysql8 community docker container.  However it has never blocked me from doing anything, so I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The mbind message is a warning. It is harmless, and should not cause any issues except performance. 
The solution was locking down the version of the mysql docker image. I changed my docker-compose.yml from...

```
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
```

to...

```
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
```

Comment: Interesing. I get it for `mysql:8`

Answer (score 0):

Switching to the nightly build worked fine for me. https://sequelpro.com/test-builds